# Running two version of elastic search on same node

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

Currently, I have node which runs ES 2.4 and for experimental purpose, I need to run another version of ES 5.6 on the same machine. As I understand, I can download a zip file of ES, unzip and run from the local directory.  Is there a way to have two version installed and run at the same time?

-Prashanth

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, just download the zip (unzip it) and modify all the accesing parameters

AKA: 
-read/write port (default is 9200)
-change the cluster_name
-etc

you also need to change the executable ./bin/elasticsearch for another one lets say ./bin/elasticsearchv5

then start your service

and access it thorugh the port you define.

advice (do not start your new instance of ES without changing these parameters)

the 2 versions are not compatible at all, so weird stuff can happen

though is not a common practice, you will have more luck deploying a digital ocean box for 10$ a month and doin your breaking changes test there than going through all this pain : )

Comment: One thing, i experienced, was that 2 different versions also cant be in one cluster at the same time. I tried to connect a different es version to a cluster and this failed, because of the different versions. So all nodes in one cluster have to be the same es version.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. zip i was able but was looking if i can install both version and run them?

Comment: the important thing here is tu understand the difference between "instance" and "node" that being said, YES you can run multiple instance and YES they can have different versions how ever NO you cant join this 2 instances in one cluster, every node in the cluster must have the same version of elasticsearch. if you want to run them independently of eachother you can, if your plan is test a new version with your data, just reindex selecting from instance and inserting in the other. (to be more clear diferent node versions CANT belong to the same cluster)